# ASP .NET Core and Azure Table Storage

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, azure-table-storage

I am new to **ASP.NET Core**, we have to implement a application to store some non-relational data (some rows in a Excel-Like table), so we decided to use Azure Tables. As I understand the **EntityFramework Core** does not support the **AzureTables**... What is the correct approach in that case?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Entity Framework is an ER mapper for databases. Azure Table Storage is a NoSQL type of solution. Please find more information on using the available NuGet package here:

[Windows Azure Storage](https://www.nuget.org/packages/WindowsAzure.Storage/)

Another great resource is [Get started with Azure Table storage using .NET](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/storage-dotnet-how-to-use-tables), which will give you all information you need to start using Table Storage.

Since you're using ASP.NET Core, you shouldn't be reading settings from web.config, but from `appsettings.json`. The `CloudStorageAccount` has a static `.Parse method` that will parse the ConnectionString and create a `CloudStorageAccount` instance for you. Have a look over here on how to read settings from appsettings.json in ASP.NET Core: [Configuration in ASP.NET Core | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration).

Comment: I tried to follow the get started, but ASP.NET Core a priori is not compatible with Azure Configuration Manager...  Package Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ConfigurationManager 3.2.3 is not compatible with netcoreapp1.1 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v1.1). Package Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ConfigurationManager 3.2.3 supports: net40 (.NETFramework,Version=v4.0)

Comment: I just created an ASP.NET Core app and added Azure Storage as a package... There's no problem. Skip that step and you'll be fine. According to the document, the ConfigurationManager package "provides a class for parsing a connection string from a configuration file". There's other ways to do that now.

Comment: I also installed OK the WindowsAzure.Storage, but not the WindowsAzure.ConfigurationManager... so you say that this is not need to make it work...

Comment: However for a beginner is hard to find the information on how and where to use the CloudStorageAccount with the ASP.NET Core infrastructure...